# Check if a column exists in a pivot query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a pivot query I need to loop through and add to another temporary table.  The pivot query is a sum of the different statuses found.  The statuses are ***Early***, ***Late***, and ***On-Time***.  Based on what the user selects, not all of the statuses are present.  So when I run the following:

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TRANSFORM Sum(recvqty) AS SumOfrecvqty " & _
                                 "SELECT supname, Sum(recvqty) AS TotalReceivedQty " & _
                                 "FROM MyReceivingOnTimeDeliveryDetail " & _
                                 "GROUP BY supname " & _
                                 "PIVOT Status", dbOpenDynaset)
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
   rs.MoveFirst
   Do While rs.EOF <> True
      rs1.AddNew
      rs1.Fields("[supname]").value = rs.Fields("[supname]").value
      rs1.Fields("[TotalReceivedQty]").value = rs.Fields("[TotalReceivedQty]").value
      rs1.Fields("[Early]").value = rs.Fields("[Early]").value
      rs1.Fields("[Late]").value = rs.Fields("[Late]").value
      rs1.Fields("[OnTime]").value = rs.Fields("[On-Time]").value
      rs1.Update
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
End If
```

If one of the statuses isn't in the results of the query then I will get an error where I am adding that value to the `MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary` table.

How do I test to for each status and if they are not there then add as 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default value to zero for any of the `MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary` fields which may not be present in the pivot query.

Then loop through the fields in the pivot query recordset and add those fields' values to the matching fields in the other recordset.

```vb
Dim fld As DAO.Field
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rs1.AddNew
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            rs1.Fields(fld.Name).value = rs.Fields(fld.Name).value
        Next
        rs1.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Incidentally, you may also find the code operates faster if you substitute `dbAppendOnly` for `dbOpenDynaset` here:

```
OpenRecordset("MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary", dbOpenDynaset)
```

I'm unsure how much of an impact that change will have.  It doesn't change the logic of what you're trying to accomplish.  And perhaps any speed impact would be insignificant.  But it won't cost you much to find out.  :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I tried dbAppendOnly vs dbOpenDynaset and didn't notice any performance differences between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You should be avoiding recordsets for simple operations, like copying with small, uniform changes, in this case. But good news: this makes everything easier!

First, use the SQL statement you already have to create a query.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db= CurrentDb
db.CreateQueryDef "qry1", "sqltext"
```

Then, from that query, SELECT INTO (or INSERT INTO) your summary table.

```
db.Execute "SELECT * INTO MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary FROM qry1"
```

Then you can add the fields if they aren't there.

```
On Error Resume Next: db.Execute "ALTER TABLE MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary ADD COLUMN Early NUMBER": Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next: db.Execute "ALTER TABLE MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary ADD COLUMN Late NUMBER": Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next: db.Execute "ALTER TABLE MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary ADD COLUMN OnTime NUMBER": Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
```

Finally, fix the nulls to zero.

```
db.Execute "UPDATE [MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary] SET [Early] = Nz([Early],0)"
db.Execute "UPDATE [MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary] SET [Late] = Nz([Late],0)"
db.Execute "UPDATE [MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary] SET [OnTime] = Nz([OnTime],0)"
```

Why do it this way? In my experience, SQL is a lot faster than recordsets.

Comment: This would be a nice way of handling it however, if a Status is not found in the Pivot query then the execute statement here does not create that field in the MyReceivingOnTimeDeliverySummary table.  So then the following update statement you have errors out because there is no such field.

Comment: "Based on what the user selects, not all of the statuses are present." Whoops, missed that sentence and totally misinterpreted this question. Well, you could definitely just modify the query so that it adds empty fields if need be. I'm going to think about how to do it, because I still believe this is a better (and more elegant) solution to your problem.

Comment: Woot! Fixed it to work for your needs. Learned some stuff along the way. (Would have been easier if Access just had DEFAULT in DAO.)

Comment: How would it be easier with `DEFAULT` in DAO?  Default doesn't alter values in existing rows.

Comment: Regardless, if you actually want to set default from Access DDL, just use ADO: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblFoo ADD COLUMN OnTime NUMBER DEFAULT 0"`

Comment: Well that seems silly. I guess what's actually silly is that if you set NOT NULL, it doesn't take on the default value. That would be intuitive.

Comment: NOT NULL is for record entry and forces the user to enter a value for that field before it can be saved.  It has nothing to do with a DEFAULT value.  Two different properties entirely.

Comment: +1 now your solution will work.  However using `ALTER TABLE tblFoo ADD COLUMN [fields] NUMBER DEFAULT 0` avoids having to use the UPDATE statements to set the fields as 0.

Comment: According to Hans (and what I've read), setting DEFAULT won't make a new column filled with default values. It will add a column with nulls, but if you were to create a new record, it would then use the default value. Haven't tried it yet, though.